# Embeds are overlapping with eachother on Mobile?

Tags: html, css

I am incredibly new to html and css, so please bear with me. I am attempting to make a website for two airbnb listings, and the webpage looks fine on a computer: [Display on Webpage Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j7he.jpg)

However, on mobile, everything looks completely different: [Display on Mobile Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC51D.png)

```css
.titlecard {
  text-align: center;
}

.airbnb-embed-frame {
  float: center;
  display: block;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0494CE;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.column {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #0494CE;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #0494CE;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Seas The Day</title>
  <link href="seastheday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="seastheday.html">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"> About
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="seasthedayabout.html">Seas The Day Top Floor</a>
        <a href="seastheday2about.html">Seas The Day Bottom Floor</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="seasthedaycontact.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="titlecard">
    <img width="50%" src="seastheday.png">


  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="airbnb-embed-frame" data-id="667282659982690585" data-view="home" style="width:450px;height:300px;margin:auto"><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/667282659982690585?check_in=2022-08-24&amp;check_out=2022-08-31&amp;guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget">View On Airbnb</a><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/667282659982690585?check_in=2022-08-24&amp;check_out=2022-08-31&amp;guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget"
          rel="nofollow">Seas The Day</a>
        <script async="" src="https://www.airbnb.com/embeddable/airbnb_jssdk"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="airbnb-embed-frame" data-id="678907740859397970" data-view="home" style="width:450px;height:300px;margin:auto"><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/678907740859397970?guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget">View On Airbnb</a><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/678907740859397970?guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget" rel="nofollow">Seas The Day 2</a>
        <script async="" src="https://www.airbnb.com/embeddable/airbnb_jssdk"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a href="seasthedayabout.html" class="button">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="seastheday2about.html" class="button">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there any way that I can make it so this doesn't occur and the mobile browser looks similar to the desktop? What are my alternatives if this is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using flexbox instead of floats, which are an older and less efficient way to do your layout. In the code below I stacked the airbnb frames vertically for mobile and tablet view, then horizontally for desktop like you had them. I had to rearrange some of your html code to achieve this, and use media queries. It was easier for me to use `style` tags to add the CSS for this example. I also had to change the width of the `airbnb-embed-frame` and remove the inline `style` rules in the html for that, as the `450px` width was causing problems with the layout in mobile view. I tried to put the code in the example setting for the answer but it wasn't showing the airbnb frames. I hope this answer is satisfactory, this is kind of my take on how I'd like to make it look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Seas The Day</title>
    <link href="seastheday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <style>
 
.titlecard {
  text-align: center;
}

.airbnb-embed-frame {
  float: center;
  display: block;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0494CE;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}



@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

.airbnb-embed-frame{
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .airbnb-embed-frame{
  width: 450px;
}
}

.column {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}

.column-2{
  margin: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #0494CE;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #0494CE;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
</style>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="seastheday.html">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn"> About
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="seasthedayabout.html">Seas The Day Top Floor</a>
          <a href="seastheday2about.html">Seas The Day Bottom Floor</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="seasthedaycontact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="titlecard">
      <img width="50%" src="seastheday.png">
  
  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="airbnb-embed-frame" data-id="667282659982690585" data-view="home" ><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/667282659982690585?check_in=2022-08-24&amp;check_out=2022-08-31&amp;guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget">View On Airbnb</a><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/667282659982690585?check_in=2022-08-24&amp;check_out=2022-08-31&amp;guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget"
            rel="nofollow">Seas The Day</a>
          <script async="" src="https://www.airbnb.com/embeddable/airbnb_jssdk"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="column-2">
          <a href="seasthedayabout.html" class="button">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="airbnb-embed-frame" data-id="678907740859397970" data-view="home" ><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/678907740859397970?guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget">View On Airbnb</a><a href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/678907740859397970?guests=1&amp;adults=1&amp;s=66&amp;source=embed_widget" rel="nofollow">Seas The Day 2</a>
          <script async="" src="https://www.airbnb.com/embeddable/airbnb_jssdk"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="column-2">
          <a href="seastheday2about.html" class="button">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
  </body>
  
  </html>
```